# In source control is it better to have one big repos or a repos per project?

Tags: svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [One SVN repository or many?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252459/one-svn-repository-or-many)

Self explanatory I feel. I got a list of related questions but I don't think any really answered this

Comment: Wait, you knowingly posted a duplicate question?

Comment: No I didn't knowingly post a duplicate, I posted a question that SOs list of suggested duplicates didn't cover. The answers given so far have revealed questions that were NOT in SOs list of suggested dupes. Obviously I wouldn't post a dupe on purpose. Geez

Comment: Before starting to write a post, did it occur to you to Google it or search on SO? "svn repositories" gave all my dupes. The SVN book also has a discussion regarding both approaches.

Comment: No I didn't want to immediately Google it because I get more targeted results on SO. I did search SO but didn't find the answer I wanted. Do you people want to get off my back?! It's a question, don't like it? close it, point to the dupes but don't make me out to be some sort of mug with no brain, WTF

Comment: Sorry but I'm a little pissed at the response. Fine to close the question, no problem. I really like SO and I put time into it with questions and answers. What's with the attitude?! "did it occur to you to google it" are you serious @Ben s?! I take pride in my work and I produce high quality products so get off your SO high horse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a debated topic and many similar questions have been asked on SO previously:

- [One SVN repository or many?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252459/one-svn-repository-or-many)
- [Subversion revision number across multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674/subversion-revision-number-across-multiple-projects)
- [SVN: one working copy, two repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580443/svn-one-working-copy-two-repositories)

Answer (score 2):

I think It depends on the size of the projects. If you have a lot of small projects, you should go with one repo, however, really large projects may benefit from having multiple repositories.

It also can depend on how many people work on the projects, if you have multiple departments working on a project, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I vote for a big repo, Apache does that way and their software ROCKS! That's a good proof of success for me.

Take a look at [their repo](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/), revision 780066 right now!